# Encrypt data with AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, aes, pkcs#5

I'm trying to encrypt a NVARCHAR variable with AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding, is this possible? how?
Greetings!!**

Comment: Are you asking ho to do this in a stored procedure or something only SQL? Also, what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I'm using sql server 2012, and yes...the instructions must be in a stored procedure. I was looking for a way and the only thing seems to be near of this, is:

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY AES128SecureSymmetricKey WITH ALGORITHM = AES_128 ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password';

but this is not working for me

Comment: @omenocal Could it be a `CLR Stored Procedure`?

Comment: Well, that could be a solution.....nevertheless i want to implement Transact-SQL...

mmm i think there's not another solution I would implement CLR